# How to trigger el-select's remote-method again after filtering a non-existing option

Tags: element-ui, element-plus

Currently using Element Plus' el-select component.
When filtering for a non-existent option, remote-method triggers fine and returns the expected result (empty since option is non-existent).
Since there's nothing to select, user clicks anywhere outside the pulldown and it closes.
When clicking the pulldown again, the previous filter query remains (remote-method does not trigger again to reinit the whole options list)
and I have no way to show the original complete list of options

1. How to trigger el-select's remote-method again after filtering a non-existing option
2. Is it possible that this is an Element Plus bug?

Here are the attributes:

```
allow-create
default-first-option
filterable
multiple
reserve-keyword
:remote="true"
:remote-method="filterOptions"
```

I've made a simple demo to illustrate the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/nathanielisaacyu/g1trex49/17/

Steps:

1. Type "aaa" in the pulldown
2. Pulldown only shows "Own" since that is a static option
3. Click anywhere outside to close pulldown
4. Click on the pulldown field
5. Options only show "Own" and not "One", "Two", "Three"

Answer (score 0):

add `@blur="filterOptions('')"` to the `el-select` tag,
it will make sure to do a clean search every time you click the select.